# Please help me understand 2D array flip

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to solve a problem in a coding trainer. But, I just could not figure this problem for the life of me.

Here is the problem:

```
You are given an m x n 2D image matrix where each integer represents a pixel. Flip it in-place along its horizontal axis.

Example:

Input image :  
              1 1
              0 0 
Modified to :   
              0 0
              1 1
```

I tried swapping rows as I traversed 2d array down the row for test case:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9


But, I end up getting 
4,5,6
7,8,9
1,2,3

instead of 


{{7,8,9},
{4,5,6},
{1,2,3}}
```

Here is the answer code.

```
public static void flipHorizontalAxis(int[][] matrix) {
    int r = matrix.length - 1, c = matrix[0].length - 1;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= r/2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= c; j++){
            temp = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[r-i][j];
            matrix[r-i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I still do not understand the answer code. Specifically, why the outer loop has "i <= r/2" and the swap has "matrix[r-i]" in the index. Why r/2 and r-i? I really do not understand why and I am totally stuck.

Can someone explain those lines so I can understand the code?

Here is the expected output for test cases:

```
1
{{1}}

1,0,0
0,0,1
{{0,0,1},{1,0,0}}

1,0
{{1,0}}

1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
{{7,8,9},{4,5,6},{1,2,3}}

1,0,1
1,0,1
{{1,0,1},{1,0,1}}
```

Comment: Run through the code slowly and patiently. As in, "suppose matrix is 5 by 5. Then r = 4, c = 4. First iteration: i = 0, j = 0: this happens. Second iteration: i = 0, j = 1: this happens." etc.

Comment: I've tested your code, and I'm getting the correct result for a 3x3 matrix, but why don't you just swap the rows instead of each individual cell.

Comment: `int r = matrix.length-1;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length/2; i++) {
            int[] temp = matrix[i];
            matrix[i] = matrix[r - i];
            matrix[r - i] = temp;
        }`

Comment: Thank y'all for helping me out. It's making more sense to me now. The explanations really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on only the double loop:

```
for (int i=0; i <= r/2; i++){
    for (int j=0; j <= c; j++){
        temp = matrix[i][j];
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[r-i][j];
        matrix[r-i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

The outer loop in `i` only ranges up to (and including) one half the height of the matrix because we want to swap each array with its "mirror" image on the other side of the median row.  That is, for a 3x3 matrix we want to do the following:

```
1,2,3   i=0
4,5,6
7,8,9   r-i=matrix.length-1 = 3-1 = 2

(swap these rows, i=i+1)

7,8,9
4,5,6   i=1, r-i=1
1,2,3

(swap the median row with itself, nothing changes)
```

If we were to allow the outer loop to run the full height of the input matrix, then after the median row we would actually *undo* the swap already done, and would just end up the original input matrix.

Comment: Ah, not its clicking somewhat!

Answer (score 0):

The number of row swaps you need to do is `matrix.length/2 - 1`. You could have written:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length/2; i++)
```

instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= r/2; i++)
```

for matrices with an odd number of rows, `matrix.length/2` and `r/2` are equal, which means that in the second form, because of the `<=`, you will swap the middle row with itself, which is useless, so I prefer the first form.

Now the index `r-i` will go downwards from the index of the last row (`r = matrix.length-1`). It's the index of the row that must be swapped with the one at index `i`.

Note that the the rows themselves are array, and it would be more efficient to swap the whole rows instead of each individual element, so here is a better solution:

```
public static void flipHorizontalAxis(int[][] matrix) {
    int r = matrix.length-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length/2; i++) {
        int[] temp = matrix[i];
        matrix[i] = matrix[r - i];
        matrix[r - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public static void flipHorizontalAxis(int[][] matrix) {
    int r = matrix.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length/2; i++) {
        --r;
        int[] temp = matrix[i];
        matrix[i] = matrix[r];
        matrix[r] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about rows themselves as arrays! Very helpful!